# Control space between two UL in HTML

Tags: html, html-lists

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="First">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="Second">
  <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

The intention is to be able to control if the first or the second list will be shown, by using a simple javascript line. For example:

```
document.getElementById('First').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('Second').style.display = 'none';
```

The problem is that I want the three items to be only one list, in case I decide to show both, but I get one list, a blank space, and then the second list. Something like this:

First item

Second item

Third item

How can I do to remove the space between both lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as following in **css file** as

```
ul{
  margin : 0 auto;
}
```

and in **html tags** write as

```
<ul id="First">
<li>First item</li>
<li>Second item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="Second">
<li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

This is used so that you can add as **many ul's** and will **display same style** as per your need.

Comment: Excellent. I used margin-bottom: 0 for the first and margin-top: 0 for the second, so I do not mess with the other margins.

Comment: yaah that's all needed. @AlejandroDC :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add

```
style="margin:0;"
```

to the ul tags like this:

```
<ul style="margin:0" id="First">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
<ul style="margin:0" id="Second">
  <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5c0getsL/2/